# Panel AutoScroll can you hide the scrollbar

Tags: c#, scrollbar, custom-controls, controls, autoscroll

So I made a custom panel and a custom scrollbar as seen below:

[image: Custom panel and scrollbar]

They are super pretty with a nice blue "border" on the right and everything.

I want to have the scrollbar work with my panel but if I turn on AutoScroll this will happen:

[image: AutoScroll scrollbar]

As you can see the scrollbar from AutoScroll is hiding my pretty pretty border..

I have done some searching around on google, but the only "real" solution I can find is to have the panel inside another panel and make the outer panel smaller to hide the scrollbar.
But that will not be suitable for what I'm doing.

I can get the scrollbar to work (if I drag the thumb) by doing this:

```
Panel.VerticalScroll.Value = Scrollbar.Value;
```

but the arrows won't work here (well, they will, but I have to move the cursor out of the Scrollbar before the changes will take place.)

Now if I turn on AutoScroll I can do this:

```
Panel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, Scrollbar.Value);
```

and it works like a charm.. but I get that ugly scrollbar on the right..
(My custom scrollbar is basically just [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14801/How-to-skin-scrollbars-for-Panels-in-C), might be easier to see the code there, instead of me having to post it here :) )

now my question is:

Is there any "smart" way of hiding the scrollbar or anyway I can get the arrows to work better with AutoScroll turned off?

Many thanks for reading!
I really hope someone can help me out with this!